# too many values to unpack error on function call

Tags: python, tokenize

I'm using the jupyter notebook to tokenize data but while proceeding, getting an error.
Code-

```
def get_vocab(lst):
    vocabcount, vocab = Counter(w for txt in lst for w in txt.split())
    return vocab, vocabcount
vocab, vocabcount = get_vocab(heads)
print (vocab[:1])
print ('...', len(vocab))
```

Output-

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-e0e24a7c7244> in <module>()
      3     return vocab, vocabcount
      4 
----> 5 vocab, vocabcount = get_vocab(heads)
      6 
      7 print (vocab)

<ipython-input-18-e0e24a7c7244> in get_vocab(lst)
      1 def get_vocab(lst):
----> 2     vocabcount, vocab = Counter(w for txt in lst for w in txt.split())
      3     return vocab, vocabcount
      4 
      5 vocab, vocabcount = get_vocab(heads)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: The line `Counter(w for txt in lst for w in txt.split())` returns only one value. You should use only 1 variable instead of 2.

Answer (score 2):

You attempt to assign *one* value returned by `Counter` to *two* variables `vocabcount, vocab`. You are most likely looking for:

```
vocab, vocabcount = zip(*Counter(whatever_you_count).items())
```

Answer (score 0):

Gotcha!!!!
I had just remove "vocabcount" from everywhere in the code and now its working